# Less Expensive Tuple Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this loop is currently working, I'm just asking for feedback on how to make it less expensive. Learning python, so all feedback is welcome! Also, not working with bananas, made 2 new  tables for the purpose of this example.

If you care for more detail about how/why I'm using this, read below.

```
import pandas as pd

def banana_validation(typeValue):
    bananaTable = pd.DataFrame([["Banana",3], ["Raspberry",1]],columns=['Type', 'TypeID'])
    if typeValue in bananaTable.values:
        return True
    return False

data = pd.DataFrame([["Banana", 58407, 3], ["Apple", 58407, 1], ["Banana", 59874, 30], ["Banana", 54651, 1], ["Berry", 13546, 1]], columns=['Type', 'ItemID', 'Number'])

def messege_printer(data):
    df = data
    output = ()
    message = ' is not a valid type'
    linebreak = '<br>'
    for index, value in df['Type'].iteritems():
        if banana_validation(value) != True:
             output = output+(value+message,linebreak,)
    return output

messege_printer(data)
```

I am creating a 'simple' web app to allow users to upload a spreadsheet and ultimately upload it into our database. Like any good data person, I need to validate that the 'Type' of value they are entering already exists. 'banana_validation' essentially is a replica of a function that queries our system and verifies that the value exists. 'messege_printer' function is ran whenever the user clicks an 'upload' button, and reads whatever the user uploaded.

**Why a tuple?** This is the only way I can pass a line break through the [dash framework](https://plotly.com/dash/). My actual 'output' variable returns something like this:

```
output = ('line 1', html.Br(), 'line 2')
```

layout of app (if anyone cares):

- database.py: banana_validation
- app_layout.py: messege_printer

Thank you so much!

Comment: why can't you just pick all records in data that do not match bananaTable without a loop?

Comment: bananaTable is a query that I am running to verify that those records exists. I presume it's this very action that is causing the greatest delay as speed is not a problem when I run the banana example.

Comment: Look at my options

Comment: A few things can be done.1: You can extract the values from the database into a variable and then check against that. 2. You can extract all the values of `'Type'` from the main dataframe using df.column.unique. Then you have fewer things to do

Answer (score 2):

- Is this an actual bottleneck in the application? It doesn't seem like it should be expensive enough to warrant optimisation.
- If it is an problem, the loop can either append to a list, or `yield` the values (from a helper function), then only contruct a tuple once.

  ```
    output = []
    for index, value in df['Type'].iteritems():
        if not banana_validation(value):
             output.extend(value + message, linebreak)
    return tuple(output)
  ```

  It's even possible that the framework will accept a list or a generator, in which case you wouldn't need to construct the tuple at all; just `yield` directly from the loop as it is.

  ```
    for index, value in df['Type'].iteritems():
        if not banana_validation(value):
             yield value + message
             yield linebreak
  ```

Comment: Hey @sabik this is not actually a bottleneck if it works with a small 'df' table. If it has a bunch of rows, I can see it being a huge delay because I am querying the database (bananaTable is a replacement table where I am actually saying `'Select count(type) from bananaTable Where type = {}'`) every time it's verifying each value. I'm going to give these suggestions a shot. Thanks so much!

Comment: Measure, don't guess, where the delays are.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Use df.colname.unique()

It looks like you just want the list of all `Type` in dataframe `data` that are not in `bananaTable`. You can do that with these three lines. Pandas allows you to get the unique values in a column. You can take the values from both dataframes and then check if one is in the other.

```
data_list = data.Type.unique().tolist()
banana_list = bananaTable.Type.unique().tolist()
missing_list = [item for item in data_list if item not in banana_list]

print (missing_list)
```

The output of this will be:

```
['Apple', 'Berry']
```

## Option 2: Use pd.merge()

I am not sure what you are trying to do. If you are trying to get the dataframes to send you a list of record that are not in `bananaTable`, then you can do something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
bananaTable = pd.DataFrame([["Banana",3], ["Raspberry",1]],columns=['Type', 'TypeID'])
data = pd.DataFrame([["Banana", 58407, 3], ["Apple", 58407, 1], ["Banana", 59874, 30], ["Banana", 54651, 1], ["Berry", 13546, 1]], columns=['Type', 'ItemID', 'Number'])

temp = data[pd.merge(data,bananaTable, on='Type',how='left',indicator=True)._merge != 'both']
temp_lst = temp.Type.values.tolist()
```

The dataframe `temp` will store all the rows that do not match with `bananaTable`. Since you want only the `Type`, you can convert it into a list. That list can be passed to `messege_printer`. You iterate through that list and combine the data as you need.

This will reduce the need to iterate through the full `data` dataframe and lookup `bananaTable` for each row.

```
def messege_printer(x):
    output = ()
    message = ' is not a valid type'    
    linebreak = '<br>'
    for value in x:
        output = output+(value+message,linebreak,)
    return output

print (messege_printer(temp_lst))
```

The output of this will be:

```
('Apple is not a valid type', '<br>', 'Berry is not a valid type', '<br>')
```

Comment: Hey @Joe , thanks for this suggestion. this would work for static tables, but I actually need to query our database. Maybe I should've been more explicit about that in my ask. This is cool though, I think I might use this in another part of my project- pd.merge  Thanks!